# Add second webapp application in JHipster Gateway

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

Is there a way to add second front end application in JHipster Gateway besides the one that is by default in `src/main/webapp`?

This application was created to have server and react client, but we want another, second client in it.

Namely, we would like to save the existing webapp in order for the PO, PM and QA to be able to use swagger and entities and to add through entities new data. The main UI should be then served from some other folder, like webapp2.

Is something like this even possible in JHipster?

Comment: Anything is possible with code. I'm not sure how you would do it with JHipster.

Comment: You can probably do it by adding a context path, see https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#building-an-executable-jar--war-file Alternatively you could manage this by setting a reverse proxy like nginx in front of 2 gateways

Comment: Hi. Thank you both for answering. Could you @GaëlMarziou tell me what you ment by 2 gatewayw?

Comment: I was just suggesting than rather than trying to put 2 webapps into a single gateway, you could have 2 gateways and make them look integrated by using a reverse proxy upfront like nginx. The webapps bundles could even be served directly by nginx.